# Replacing NA values of a group with summed values of other columns

Tags: r

I have the following data frame, where often an 'id' did not receive 'a' at all. So for that 'id' all the values in column 'a' will be NA.

```
  id  a  b  c
1 14  1  2 NA
2 14  2  4  1
3 15 NA  8  1
4 15 NA NA  3
5 15 NA  1  3
6 26  2  4  4
7 26 NA  2  0
8 26  2  9  1
```

If an id did not receive 'a' at all I would like to replace those NA values with b+c. But only if b **and** c are present. So the dataframe will look like this:

```
  id  a  b  c
1 14  1  2 NA
2 14  2  4  1
3 15  9  8  1
4 15 NA NA  3
5 15  4  1  3
6 26  2  4  4
7 26 NA  2  0
8 26  2  9  1
```

Right now I have this, but can't find a way to do it based on id. It also changes row 7, which should not happen because id 26 did receive some 'a'

```
df$a <- ifelse(is.na(df$a), df$b+df$c, df$a)

  id  a  b  c
1 14  1  2 NA
2 14  2  4  1
3 15  9  8  1
4 15 NA NA  3
5 15  4  1  3
6 26  2  4  4
7 26  2  2  0
8 26  2  9  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `coalesce` after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(a = if(all(is.na(a))) coalesce(a, b + c) else a)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id     a     b     c
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    14     1     2    NA
#2    14     2     4     1
#3    15     9     8     1
#4    15    NA    NA     3
#5    15     4     1     3
#6    26     2     4     4
#7    26    NA     2     0
#8    26     2     9     1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 26L, 26L, 26L), 
    a = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 2L), b = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 
    NA, 1L, 4L, 2L, 9L), c = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using logical `rowSums`.

```
s <- !abs(rowSums(sapply(dat[,3:4], as.logical))) %in% c(NA, 1)
dat[s, ]$a <- with(dat[s, ], b + c)
#   id  a  b  c
# 1 14  1  2 NA
# 2 14  5  4  1
# 3 15  9  8  1
# 4 15 NA NA  3
# 5 15  4  1  3
# 6 26  8  4  4
# 7 26 NA  2  0
# 8 26 10  9  1
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(text="id  a  b  c
1 14  1  2 NA
2 14  2  4  1
3 15 NA  8  1
4 15 NA NA  3
5 15 NA  1  3
6 26  2  4  4
7 26 NA  2  0
8 26  2  9  1", header=TRUE)
```